# Eclipse Luna + ADT -freeze 99% when running app on mac

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I was using Eclipse Luna + ADT, everything was fine, but today, when I try to run my project in my cel, it freezes to 99%, and then says:

```
Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

and then :

```
Unhandled loop expected
```

The only solution I find is go back to ADT Bundle ( w/ Kepler), but I don't love this solution as Eclipse is very outdate...

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What version of ADT plugin? I'm not sure if it will help, but you can increase the amount of heap space allocated to Eclipse by editing the `eclipse.ini` file inside ``Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS`

Comment: I guess my ADT is updated, let me one minute I will tell you the exact version. I thing increasing heap space will not change anything, because I have 10 GB of memory, and it seems to consume all of it. I think he is going crazy !

Comment: ADT was outdated, so I've made the update to v23.0.3.1327240, but it didn't change anything !

Comment: No matter how much memory your machine has, the important thing is how much are you letting Eclipse use for JAVA. And for increasing that you have to edit eclipse.ini. This thread is old, though, so I bet you have already realized it. Just for the record...

Answer (score 0):

This [Link](https://docs.oseems.com/general/application/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) Helped me  a lot.

As what is said in the link above, you should increase the size of memory used by eclipse.

Just open the eclipse.ini file, located in the same folder as eclipse.exe is located by a text editor.
The original eclipse.ini file looks like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Now change the last 2 lines to:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

You can also increase the value of MaxPermSize, as the following:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

This solution helped me and solve my problem.

Good luck